# What is the correct way to overload an operator of a primitive type in C++?

Tags: c++, matrix, operator-overloading

I am trying to write a simple matrix class to use in one of my course projects. The definition of the class is shown below.

```cpp
#ifndef MATRIX_HH
#define MATRIX_HH

#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <omp.h>

#include "MatrixException.hh"

#define F77_CALL(x) x ## _
#define F77_NAME(x) F77_CALL(x)

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

extern void F77_NAME(dgemm)(const char *transa,const char *transb,
    const int *m, const int *n, const int *k,
    const double *alpha, const double *a, const int *lda,const double *b, 
    const int *ldb, const double *beta, double *c, const int *ldc);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

class Matrix {
private:
    /** The number of rows. */
    int m;
    /** The number of columns. */
    int n;
protected:
    /** The matrix entries, stored in row-major order. */
    double *data;
public:
    /** The matrix dimensions (as an array). */
    int *dims;
    Matrix(int m_,int n_);
    Matrix(int m_,int n_,double *data_);
    ~Matrix();
    void shape();
    void print();
    const double &operator()(int i) const;
    const double &operator()(int i,int j) const;
    double &operator()(int i,int j);
    Matrix transpose();
    Matrix operator + (const double c);
    Matrix operator - (const double c);
    Matrix operator * (const double c);
    Matrix operator + (const Matrix &B);
    Matrix operator - (const Matrix &B);
    Matrix operator * (const Matrix &B);
    double sum();
};
#endif
```

An example of how this class is used would be:

```cpp
// Two random matrices
Matrix A(3,3),B(3,3);
// Matrix addition
Matrix C=A+B;
// Matrix-matrix multiplication
Matrix D=A*B;
// Add a scalar to each entry of A
Matrix E=A+1.;
```

This is already plenty of functionality, but I would find it useful for my matrix class to have the ability to do something like this:

```cpp
Matrix A(3,3);
// This should be equivalent to A+1.
Matrix B=1.+A;
```

How can I overload the `+` operator of a primitive type like `double` to accomplish something like this? I tried declaring something like:

```cpp
Matrix double::operator+(const Matrix&B);
```

However, this gives an error when I try to compile.

```sh
g++-10 -fopenmp -Wall -std=c++11 -O3   -framework Accelerate -c Matrix.cc
In file included from Matrix.cc:1:
Matrix.hh:53:2: error: two or more data types in declaration of 'operator+'
   53 |  Matrix double::operator + (const Matrix &B);
      |  ^~~~~~
```

What would be the correct way to do this?

PS. I know there exist linear algebra libraries like `Eigen` that provide a lot of functionality "out of the box". However, since this is for a course project, I have chosen to write my own matrix class.

Comment: Useful reference, but might not be seen as an answer to this question until you know the answer to this question: [The basic rules and idioms for operator overloading: The Decision between Member and Non-member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading#4421729)

Answer (score 3):

You can add overload operator as non-member function.

```
Matrix operator+(double c, const Matrix&B) {
    return B + c;  // calling Matrix::operator + (const double c)
}
```

---

PS: Better to mark operators implemented as member-function as `const`, they're not supposed to perform modification on the object to be called on.

Comment: If you do this (and you should), you will need to declare the function as a friend of the Matrix class so it can access the protected and private parts of Matrix.

Comment: @Sniggerfardimungus For this case we can just call `Matrix::operator + (const double c)`.

Comment: Fair enough. Old habits die hard. =]

Comment: @Sniggerfardimungus Well, it's a good habit, especially when overload all operators as non-member.

Comment: @ErickRuiz You should mark member operators as `const`, e.g. `Matrix operator + (const double c) const;` ...

Answer (score 1):

It can be done in this way:

In the class, add:

```
class Matrix {
   ...
public:
  friend Matrix operator + (double a, const Matrix &B);
   ...
}
```

Then, define out of the class:

```
Matrix operator + (double a, const Matrix &B)
{
   ...
}
```

Best regards.